# Changing default "Taxonomy term" view to add a filter and change path in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I am trying to do a seemingly simple thing but unable to come up with anything.

I'll be specific here for what I want to achieve. I want to clone the existing `Taxonomy term` which has a path of `/taxonomy/term/%`. After cloning this view, I wanna make the following changes to it:-

- Change the name to `Document of Taxonomy Term`
- Add a filter to this view of a field called is_document. It's a checkbox which is when clicked shows that this node of my taxonomy term is a document.
- Change path to `/taxonomy/term/documents/%`, which shows that I am opening all nodes of this term which are marked as document.

Now when I open my site, let's say with the URL `www.mysite.com/organisation/company/documents`, it doesn't pick the view. The URL `www.mysite.com/organisation/company` works as it picks the default Drupal View.

Any idea what I can do here?

I hope I was able to explain efficiently.

### UPDATE

I used TVI, but it changes all the pages of my taxonomy terms. I don't wanna change my current scenario where normal taxonomy term pages are opened through /taxonomy/term/% (native Drupal view). I just wanna open all taxonomy terms with a document filter when /taxonomy/term/documents/% view is selected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to download and install [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) for URL aliases patterns.

In your Views, you set the path at: `taxonomy/term/documents/%`

In Pathauto settings, you to go "Patterns", then scroll to the taxonomy section where you can set a new URL pattern: `[term:vocabulary]/[term:name]/documents`

Then, go to `Update` tab and update all the paths for Taxonomy.

Enjoy your new Views.